# Mahout: Running grouplens example gives ClassNotFound exception

Tags: java, mahout

I'm running the beginner Mahout recommender tutorial on [this site](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-documentation.html). I get to the step where I run jetty to start the reccomender:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Jetty seems to start, but is unable to find the grouplens example jar. IE I get this exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommender

After doing some research I found [several](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Jetty-Http-error-404-td1852221.html) [questions](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/13885) with no clear resolution to this issue. Or solutions are listed but no feedback is given as to what worked. I tried upping the memory for maven from the recommended 1024 MB to 2048 MB, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with Maven dependencies. It seems as one of the thread above suggests (but without feedback as to whether it works or not) the correrct solution is to edit the integration/pom.xml file and include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>mahout-examples</artifactId>
  <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I believe this may be related to having an older version of Mahout in my maven repo.